Nginx stopped doing it job: cant bind to ports, doesn't reverse proxy
Well, I tried to self-host and reverse proxy a webpage for my self-hosted discord bot with this guide, but it wasn't really working for me: I have the bot's webpage enabled w/ auto-startup, I have added its port in my router and added in Ubuntu by using sudo ufw allow 42356, it opens with 192.168.1.64:42356, but when I added a config for it inside /etc/nginx/sites-available/ and synced with ../sites-enabled/ I couldn't reach the red.mydomain.com, it is just infinite loading and gives a timeout message with fact that it works great for anyone else and their support couldn't understand what's the case of it.
Reddash nginx config is the same as in the docs:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name red.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:42356;
    }
}

Today I tried to reverse proxy a Portainer webpage to portainer.mydomain.com and of course it is not working too.
Portainer nginx config:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name portainer.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name portainer.mydomain.com;

    # Reverse proxy to Portainer
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:9443;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # If Portainer has its own SSL certificate, you might need to disable SSL verification
        proxy_ssl_verify off;
    }
}

I left portainer.mydomain.com loading in the background and it gave me a window to log in to my router webpage for some reason, which is the main problem, I guess. Yes, I know there is p.portainer.mydomain.com on a screenshot, because I was just testing, it doesn't change anything.

Also domain control page gives some kind of messages that domains which connected to my IP have DNS not allowed or something (tried to translate from my language as good as I could). I just edited my portainer nginx config from portainer.mydomain.com to p.portainer.mydomain.com and when I open portainer.mydomain.com it successfully opens a default/temporary page of my domain (like nginx has a default page)
it looks like the issue is in the router?

Please edit your post to focus on one and only one issue.

for some reason my domain redirects to router page, not to the service I host. thats all I guess
